# Linux - python os.system(cmd) calls another python exe but generates an indinite loop

Tags: python

I always use the 'X' at the top right to end my scripts.
I made a script that when clicked on 'X' launches another script that creates an xlsx file. At the end of the latter a QMessageBox is executed and everything should stop when you press OK. In reality, pressing OK reruns the script that creates the xlsx file. This repeats endlessly and I haven't found a way to get out of it except with a system logout

**My.py**

```
[...]
def makexlsx(self, arg1, arg2, arg3 = False):
        if arg3 == 'go':
            os.system('%s %s %s' % ('/home/PycharmProjects/xlsxfile/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.10/xlsxfile', arg1, arg2))
            sys.exit(0)
```

xlsxfile exec which creates the xlsx file then run following message handler

```
[...]
        wb.save(my_path)
        elapsed_time = round(time.time() - starttime, 2)
        Functions.message_handler(filename + " is ready   Etime: " + str(elapsed_time))
        sys.exit(0)


def message_handler(message):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        print(message)
        msg.setText(str(message))
        msg.setWindowTitle(" BYE ")
        msg.exec_()
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Note that there are serious security risks in using `os.system` with string concatenation and no escaping. If you're going to do this -- and I strongly advise against it -- be sure you trust both your filenames and your arguments.

Comment: For beginner-level background, maybe see https://portswigger.net/web-security/os-command-injection

Comment: Both scripts are local and the resulting xlsx file will go to a cloud via secure communication. So the security is not my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the solution, it probably won't be technically the best but it's right for me.
For a reason that is not clear to me none of the `sys.exit(0)` had any effect so the xlsxfile script returned to `My.py` triggering an infinite loop. I replaced `sys.exit(0)` with `os._exit(0)` after the call to os.system (%s ....) and this way My.py ends